# ag grid react: server-side row model

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a database with over a million records with 111 rows, so when I try to load the data upfront with ag-grid, memory will run out and it will not load.

I have been looking at the following link for server-side row modelling.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-datasource/

As a fullstack newbie, I don't really understand what they're doing here and my question is what they're doing in the createFakeServer function and what would I need to do to make it a 'real' server in my case.

I am open to repos/projects that use serverside modelling for reactjs as references.

Comment: `createFakeServer` is just a mock ("fake") ajax call - you'd replace it by creating a real ajax call to your own server (perhaps using a library like axios), which would load the relevant page of data from your database and return it to the client.